# What is the difference between Selenium Webdriver and SoapUI?

Tags: java, rest, user-interface, selenium, automation

I have just started to get into using selenium webdriver for creating tests for websites filling out forms clicking buttons etc. What else can Selenium be used for? Is this the main purpose for selenium>? testing the filling out of forms, checking elements exist and clicking buttons as if it is simulating a web user?

I understand that this is UI testing, however, I need a tool for service tests. I came across SOAPUI, however, is this not just the same type of tool as selenium? I can see that SOAPUI also has load testing and security testing but isn't this something that can be done using selenium?

What is the main differences between these 2 tools? Also what tools can I look to use to test REST API's?

Thanks.

Comment: SOAPUI can test both WSDL and RESTFUL APIs[Screenshot of SOAPUI Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOui3.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this the main purpose for selenium? testing the filling out of forms, checking elements exist and clicking buttons as if it is simulating a web user?

**Exactly right**.

Selenium is just used for emulating user-actions.  Selenium doesn't necessarily do any validating automatically (other than page loads) however, that's up to you.

> is [SoapUI] not just the same type of tool as selenium?

Selenium and SoapUI are under the same bracket of tools, but they are **not** the same tools.  Both Selenium and SoapUI are used for *testing* the web.  **SoapUI** specializes in the web service end, and Selenium specializes in automating the actual web application.

> I can see that SOAPUI also has load testing and security testing but isn't this something that can be done using selenium?

It *can* be done with Selenium yes, but i'm not sure how often people do this.  SoapUI does just fine with load testing and security testing since those can be accomplished by hitting the back-end [noting again, that selenium hits front-end, not back.]

> What is the main differences between these 2 tools?

Let's take a look at their respective definitions:

**Selenium**: *Automate web browsers. That's it.*

**SoapUI**: ... *Testing tool for API's*

So, in essence: Selenium can test the front-end, and SoapUI can test the back-end.  They are mutually exclusive.

> Also what tools can I look to use to test REST API's?

This question - however, is out-of-scope for StackOverflow, therefore I will refrain from answering.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to answer my question. That has cleared a lot up for me.

Comment: my pleasure :)  awesome! i'm so glad to hear that